# How to sort NSArray of objects based on two different languages

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have an array. The array have name of places(strings) in Two different languages. i.e Arabic and English. I want to sort array in a way that Arabic words come first and then English.

Furthermore, I have a function which returns me a Boolean True/False and tells me whether the string is in English or not. The array will contain only 2 languges.

Thanks everyone.As I was short on time so I just followed an old school method. Used 2 For loops and copied data from source array to new array on the basis of language. 
Will look into some useful information provided by users here. Thanks everyone.

Comment: You'd have to maintain the flag yourself, using the knowledge only you have about what language is contained in the custom object.  You can then use this to influence the sort order.

Answer (score 0):

you should try like this

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"prop" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [NSSortDescriptor
        sortDescriptorWithKey:@"prop"
                    ascending:YES
                   comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id _Nonnull obj1,
                                                  id _Nonnull obj2){
                       if( [self isArabic:obj2] && [self isArabic:obj1])
                           return NSOrderedSame;
                       if ([self isArabic:obj2])
                           return NSOrderedAscending;
                       else if ([self isArabic:obj1])
                           return NSOrderedDescending;
                       else
                           return NSOrderedSame;
                   }];
[self.arrList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2]];
```

Comment: If two words are arabic, that does not mean that the words are ordered same. This apply to two english words, too.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad he did't tell that he want sort or classify

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad he wrote arabic first only

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad that's why I commented if you need any update

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad now its fine, I have updated as per your suggestion

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Thanks

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad its better then long comments

Comment: No. :-) However, I do not understand your edit. What is `prop`? It looks like the language property. But in such a case you would now sort it two times for the language and no time "inside" the language?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad prop is just the placeholder, not an issue normal people will understand, it will automatically sort first alphabetically then language wise

Comment: Ah, I see. But there is still no alphabetical sorting?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad First sortDescriptor will sort alphabetically, normal people will understand

Comment: So I'm not normal. Did you check it?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Sir I always check before going into debate or discussion, you are extra ordinary person with huge experience of coding, book writing and lawyer

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad So see, you are not normal like us

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I totally respect your contribution to society, you are inspiration for us

Comment: Aha, you checked it. So my computer is not normal, too.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad it must be super computer but I don't know if Apple is allowing super computer :D

Comment: Do you have access to a location where you can upload your check?

Comment: I am not getting you, I am normal you know

Comment: Ah, I thought so. :-)

Comment: I am not getting you,

Comment: I was pretty sure, that you cannot upload a project with your code running properly. I think that we can stop the discussion right now.

Answer (score 0):

So you have that "function". I assume that this is a method (I name it `-isEnglish`) in a category of `NSString`. (If it is not, make it.)

Then you have two approaches:

A. Nested Sort Descriptors

You can do that with two sort descriptors:

```
NSSortDescriptor *languageSorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"isEnglish" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *wordSorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedWords = [words sortedArrayUsingSortDescriptors:@[languageSorter, wordSorter];
```

B. Custom Sorting

You can set your own sorting using a comparator:

```
NSArray *sortedWords = [words sortedArrayUsingComparator:
^(id word1, id word2)
{
  // 1. english, 2. arabic
  if( [word1 isEnglish] && ![word2 isEnglish] )
  {
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
  }

  // 1. arabic, 2. english
  else if ( ![word1 isEnglish] && [word2 isEnglish] )
  {
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
  }

  // Both words in the same language, do your "usual" comparision
  …
}
```

An additional approach would be to divide the array into two separated arrays using `NSPredicate` and `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` (`NSArray´).